# MySQL concurrent UPDATES

Tags: mysql, concurrency

Say we have the following situation **in an application** using MySQL where a User can buy an Item and each Item has a single buyer but the Item's price may change.

Pseudocode :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

seenPrice = SELECT price FROM Item
    WHERE id = ABC AND buyer IS NULL

UPDATE Item SET buyer = X
    WHERE id = ABC AND buyer IS NULL AND price = seenPrice

COMMIT
```

The `seenPrice` variable and the `buyer IS NULL AND price = seenPrice` checks in the UPDATE statement serve as an Optimistic Lock mean to make sure that any concurrency issues *do not come up*.

In a multi - threaded enviroment where a thread A and a thread B are past the `SELECT` statement at the same time and say thread A executes the `UPDATE` statement first then concurrency is not a concern **but is it possible that both A and B execute the `UPDATE` statement at the same exact time?** For context the application is being developed using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible that both A and B execute the `UPDATE` statement at the same exact time?

The statements can potentially *start executing* at the same time, but they cannot update the same row simultaneously. An update statement must [acquire an exclusive lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) on the row before it can be modified, and lock acquisition is an atomic operation that is strictly serialized, meaning that one of the concurrent sessions will always acquire the lock first, and the other sessions will be blocked.

Lock acquisition is always atomic, regardless of the DBMS or storage engine -- if it weren't, it would be completely useless as a concurrency control mechanism.

The locking mechanism does not care if your application is written using optimistic or pessimistic locking approach -- what changes is the time when the lock is taken. With pessimistic locking you expect there to be a lot of concurrent activity and you want to ensure that your transaction succeeds (at the cost of preventing concurrent updates):

| Application | Database |
| --- | --- |
| `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` | Acquire lock |
| Do something else |  |
| ... |  |
| `UPDATE ...` |  |
| `COMMIT` | Release lock |

With optimistic locking you don't expect much concurrent activity, so the probability of your application failing to complete the update is low, and you don't keep the lock for long:

| Application | Database |
| --- | --- |
| `SELECT ...` |  |
| Do something else |  |
| ... |  |
| `UPDATE ...` | Acquire lock |
| `COMMIT` | Release lock |

Comment: I see but is the atomicity of the lock acquisition independent of storage engine (InnoDB, MyISAM etc as the link your provided refers to InnoDB)? Furthermore is the implementation above compliant with the concept of Optimistic Lock? I am asking as it is a concept that I came across recently.

Comment: Locking is mostly dependent on the storage engine. MyISAM does not support transactions or row-level locking at all.

Comment: @BillKarwin lock granularity is irrelevant to this question; even if it's a table- or page-level lock, its acquisition must be atomic.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was replying to the OP's comment, asking if lock acquisition is independent of storage engine. Apologies if I did not make that clear.

Comment: @mustaccio So what you are saying is that no matter the underlying details if a lock acquisition mechanism exists then it must be atomic

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for both A and B to execute the UPDATE at the exact same time. One or the other will acquire the lock on the row first, and then the other will be blocked until the winner commits.

Once the winner commits, the condition `buyer IS NULL` will no longer be true, so the UPDATE of the thread that waited will not affect it.

We can do an experiment to test this:

In window 1:

```
mysql> begin;

mysql> select * from item where id=1 and buyer is null;
+-------+----+-------+
| price | id | buyer |
+-------+----+-------+
| 19.95 |  1 |  NULL |
+-------+----+-------+
```

In window 2, do the same, start a transaction and view the price.

In window 1:

```
mysql> update item set buyer=42 where id=1 and buyer is null and price=19.95;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

In window 2:

```
mysql> update item set buyer=84 where id=1 and buyer is null and price=19.95;
(hangs, waiting)
```

In window 1:

```
mysql> commit;
```

In window 2:

```
(finishes waiting)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (4.53 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Notice zero rows matched or changed! Because the buyer was no longer null in the most recent committed version of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing `buyer IS NULL` in both statements, the processing will "work".  However, a different connection could sneak in between the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` and set `buyer`.

So, you must check to see whether the `UPDATE` actually succeeded.  If it did not, then what?  Tell  the user "Sorry you went through all the UI only to have someone else sneak in and buy the thing you wanted."  Ugh.

Instead, do `FOR UPDATE` on the `SELECT`.  That way, you can catch the issue sooner.

And do not write code that hangs on to a transaction for more than a few seconds.  That could lead to all sorts of nasty melt-downs in your application.